# nhibernate and "NOT IN" in a aggregate subquery

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, criteria

I've got an entity **Reminder** which contains a collection of **ReminderSchedule**.
This is my mapping:

```
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="Reminder" table="Reminders">
    <id name="Code" type="System.Guid">
        <column name="ReminderCode" />
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    ...
    <set access="field.pascalcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="Schedules" mutable="true">
      <key foreign-key="FK_Schedules_Reminders">
        <column name="ReminderCode" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="ReminderSchedule" />
    </set>
</class>
```

This is the mapping for the entity **ReminderSchedule**:

```
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="ReminderSchedule" table="ReminderSchedules">
    <id name="Code" type="System.Guid">
      <column name="ReminderScheduleCode" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="NextSchedule" type="System.DateTime">
      <column name="NextSchedule" index="ReminderScheduleK01" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="Reminder" foreign-key="FK_ReminderScheduleToReminder" name="Reminder">
      <column name="ReminderCode" index="ReminderScheduleK02" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
```

ReminderSchedules table contains a record for each new scedule associated with a reminder. 
I can close a schedule (Closed = 1) and reschedule a new one.
In this situation I would have a new records with Closed = 0 and I the field NextSchedule would contain the date/time of the next schedule.

I am already using **CreateCriteria** to filter the reminders and it works pretty very well. 
Now I would like to fetch the reminders which do not have any ReminderSchedule open.

I've figured out how to do it with a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Reminders
WHERE ReminderCode 
    NOT IN (
        SELECT LastReschedule.ReminderCode FROM (
        SELECT ReminderCode, MAX(NextSchedule) MaxSchedule
        FROM ReminderSchedules
        WHERE Closed = 1 
        GROUP BY ReminderCode) LastReschedule
        )
ORDER BY Reminders.ReminderCode
```

but I don't know how to translate it in a criteria valid for nhibernate.

Is there anybody out there who can help me? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: is this nhibernate version 2 or 3?

Comment: @Rippo: I am using NH 3.0.0.4000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I haven't been able to use 2 subqueries (nested) I've tried to simplify using just one subquery.
I've fetched the id of the reminder (Schedules.Reminder.Code) for the schedules closed.   Luckily for me I shouldn't have another schedule if the previous one hasn't been closed. If it happens, too bad, I won't be able to manage it.

This is the best I could do:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>("Reminders");

DetachedCriteria dCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Domain.ReminderSchedule>("Schedules")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Schedules.Reminder.Code")))
    // .Add(Projections.Max("Schedules.NextSchedule").As("MaxSchedule")))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Schedules.Closed", true));

FiltersCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Reminders.Code", dCriteria));
```

I guess this sample code is self explanatory.
I've used a **DetachedCriteria** for the subquery and I use it as a parameter for my **Criteria**.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using a [Subquery](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-subqueries).
in HQL, it should be something along the lines of (untested):

```
from Reminders as R
where R.ReminderCode not in
   ( select RS.ReminderCode
     from ReminderSchedules as RS
     where RS.NextSchedule = (select max(NextSchedule) from ReminderSchedules as Inner where RS.Closed = 1)
   )
```

even though I don't believe I hit *exactly* what you need, the link provided should help you get in the right direction.

Comment: @sJhonny: thanks for your answer. I was hoping to find something non HQL.

Comment: @LeftyX: basically, anything that can be written in HQL can be written as Criteria; It's just a little less intuitive (in my opinion, at least). Concerning the Query API- AFAIK it doesn't cover everything yet, not sure whether it's applicable for your case.

Comment: @sJhonny: Yes, I can understand that.HQL is easier but I've used Criteria and hoped I could do everything.Actually,I am almost there.I had to simplify my query a little bit but I've achieved what I wanted (almost).I'll post my solution soon.

Comment: @LeftyX: you surely can. as I said- AFAIK criteria is equivalent to HQL, so anything you can write in HQL you can in criteria. I myself am not the greatest expert in Criteria (I prefer using Linq whenever I can), but if you want I could take a crack at this problem. Let me know how you're getting on.

Comment: @sJhonny: thanks.I'll put some code tomorrow.I've founds different examples on the web and put something together.

Comment: @sJhonny: I've answered my question with the best I could achieve.