# NHibernate 3 and Future with Lazy Load

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I've got an entity Reminder which contains a collection of Schedules (see the mapping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061649/nhibernate-and-not-in-in-a-aggregate-subquery)). 
I didn't want my collection Schedules to be lazy loaded so I set the attribute to false:

```
<set access="field.pascalcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="Schedules" mutable="true">
      <key foreign-key="FK_Schedules_Reminders">
        <column name="ReminderCode" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="ReminderSchedule" />
</set>
```

In one query I didn't want to load the collection so I've set the SetFetchMode to Lazy:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
FiltersCriteria.SetFetchMode("Schedules", FetchMode.Lazy);
```

Running my query I noticed that Nhibernate was running the query for the reminders and then, for each reminder, it was running single queries to fetch the Schedules.
Here is the code I was using:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
FiltersCriteria.SetFetchMode("Schedules", FetchMode.Lazy)
Result = FiltersCriteria.List<Domain.Reminder>();
```

After a little bit of struggle I've changed my code using the Future and everything worked fine:

```
ICriteria FiltersCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Reminder>();
FiltersCriteria.SetFetchMode("Schedules", FetchMode.Lazy)
Result = FiltersCriteria
    .Future<Domain.Reminder>()
    .ToList<Domain.Reminder>();
```

Why doesn't it work simply using FetchMode.Lazy? Why do I have to use Future?
If I set the lazy mode in my schema, obviously, everything works as I would expect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override a `lazy="false"` in the mapping with `SetFetchMode`.

Personally, I recommend you **never** use `lazy="false"`. Recommended read: [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)

Comment: thanks for your answer.What I was trying to figure out is why in my 1st example (without Future) it doesn't override?! You said you don't like to use lazy=false.What would you do if you want to load all the details of each order? Thanks.

Comment: @LeftyX: I would use either `batch-size` on the collections with a reasonable value, or a manual call (with or without Future), as described [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate)

Comment: what would you suggest if you wanted to load an entity and a detail entity in a non-lazy mode?

Comment: @LeftyX: you can use `SetFetchMode`/`Fetch`/`join fetch` depending on your query method.